# Sumar columnas de una bd y comparar con columna de otra base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo dos BD una con cambios de stock de forma continua (base 2) y otra (base1)que se actualiza con los valores de la BD2.

BASE 1

| id1 | cod1 | cant1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 3 |
| 2 | bbb | 5 |
| 3 | ccc | 8 |
| 4 | eee | 8 |

BASE 2

| id2 | cod2 | cant2 | deposito |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | aaa | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | bbb | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | bbb | 25 | 2 |
| 5 | ccc | 11 | 1 |
| 6 | ccc | 10 | 2 |
| 7 | ddd | 12 | 1 |
| 8 | ddd | 4 | 2 |
| 9 | eee | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | eee | 4 | 2 |

Tengo una query de **sql server** que muestra la diferencia de stock entre ambas

```
SELECT
base2.cod2, base2.cant2
from 
base2
LEFT JOIN
base1
on
base2.cod2 = base1.cod1
WHERE
base2.deposito = 1
AND
(base2.cant2 != base1.cant1
OR  base1.cant1 IS NULL)
ORDER BY
base2.cod2
```

El resultado de esto muestra los sgte:

| cod2 | cant2 |
| --- | --- |
| ccc | 11 |
| ddd | 12 |
| eee | 4 |

Ahora lo que necesito es que de la bd2, que tiene stock en dos depósitos, lo que quiero es sumar ese stock por articulo, comparar con la bd1 y solo mostrar el stock de la bd2 que es distinto en la bd1.

RESULTADO ESPERADO

| cod2 | cant2 |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 7 |
| bbb | 30 |
| ccc | 21 |
| ddd | 16 |

El articulo **eee** no se muestra ya que la suma de stock de los dos deposito de la bd2 coincide con las cantidad de la bd1.

He tratado de usar una combinación de sum,group by y having. Pero no logro obtener el resultado que espero.
Aguardo por sugerencias y/o correciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver esto, primero tienes que hacer la suma de tu primer tabla (una tabla no es una base de datos. Después puedes usar ese resultado como una tabla derivada y unirla a la otra tabla. En este caso, lo hago usando una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
WITH cteBase2 AS(
    SELECT cod2,
           SUM(cant2) AS cant2
    FROM base2
    GROUP BY cod2
)
SELECT b2.cod2, 
       b2.cant2
from  cteBase2 b2
LEFT JOIN base1 b1 ON b2.cod2 = b1.cod1
WHERE (b2.cant2 != b1.cant1
OR  b1.cant1 IS NULL)
ORDER BY b2.cod2;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis por tu ayuda, me fue muy útil y logre lo que necesitaba.